# ADC is not correctly working

Tags: batteries, adc, lipo

I build this schematic that was recommended to me in [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/663957/read-battery-voltage-with-ads1110):

[image]

My entire schematic then would be:

[image]

And this is how it looks on the PCB:

[image]

If I attach a 4.15V battery, the differential between VIN+ and VIN- is 600mV, if I attach a battery that has 4V I read 590mV, if I attach a 3.9V battery I read 560mV. The difference in voltage should be far greater. Does anybody know what I messed up? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You are powering the chip with VDD of 3.3V and trying to measure voltages from battery that are beyond the maximum of VDD + 0.2V which the chip can handle.

Comment: The Chip has a differential input of 0 - 5V. Because of it's 2.048V built in voltage reference. The above schematic is a voltage divider (sort of) i thought, isn't that the case?

Comment: There is no voltage divider anywhere. Just e.g. 4.2V from battery, a series resistor, and a chip input that has an absolute maximum rating of 3.6V (when used with 3.3V supply) before it gets damage.

Comment: I added the picture of the Datasheet, and there it says +5V to 0V, or does that mean that in that specific schematic the VDD is also 5V?

Comment: That diagram never mentions the supply voltage, but as it is only a basic connection diagram, it does not have to. The input voltage range for the chip is specified in the data sheet. Thus, that diagram would require 5V for VDD, yes.

Comment: Okay what would you recommend me? I have an ESP32-S3, I want to have it measure a battery but without any big power loss (because a voltage divider also dissipates heat right)?. I just wanted a ADC that can handle 0-5V even if connected to a 3.3V source, but I guess that is not logical? Do you know any better way to do this, or do you think the ADS1110 is a good choice but the input should be lowered to 0-2.048 using a voltage div?

Comment: @CemPamirBana I think you should likely open a new question about what you should do, other people may have better ideas for your situation. But this specific question about what is wrong with the circuit is now answered with a correct answer.

Comment: But I do measure 600mV differential, and that is what I want or not. I want to map the input 2.8V - 4.2V to the differential output with that circuit above. You say that it is bullshit?

Comment: If the ADC is powered by 3.3V you can't have 4.2V on the input pin and measure it. With 5V you can have 4.2V on input pin and measure it. The circuit won't work if you have 3.3V supply. There is 600mV measured between pins, because the input protection diodes kick in and limits the input voltage to prevent chip from frying up, current being limited by R40. The measurement is invalid because input voltage is out of range, as it can't be 3.3V + 0.6V as then the chip absolute maximum input voltage has been exceeded and the chip has been damaged.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, to use a voltage divider with an output of 1.4 to 2.1 V for the battery voltage of 2.8 to 4.2 V, but it will only draw current when a sample signal is provided by the MCU. You could also provide an offset to allow for a full range signal to the ADC - this just illustrates how to disconnect the battery from the measurement circuitry to eliminate wasted power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA7Xp6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Battery current]